# Should one living in Israel leave?

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, army-military-war, state-of-israel

The Torah commands us, ‘Venishmartem meod lenafshotechem' ['You shall take care exceedingly of your lives' — Deut. 4:15).

It seems anyone living in Israel is in grave danger due to the recent advances in missile technology and WMP by Arab enemies who are hell-bent on destroying Israel.

Given the clear life threatening danger of staying in Israel, does the above Torah commandment apply, whereby one should pack up and move out?

Some say that Israel relies on miracles so it's OK, but the Talmud in Shabbat 32a says clearly that one should never put himself in danger and rely on a miracle.

ADDITION here's a source for the current seriousness of the situation: "Israel's Prime Minister, Benjamin Netanyahu, recently said that Israel is “the most threatened nation on the planet.” He was referring to the threatening ring of missiles aimed at the Jewish state from regimes such as Hamas, Hezbollah, Syria, and Iran" http://canadafreepress.com/index.php/article/55711

another source http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/207485 (2016-2-3)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11459/should-retroactive-divorce-a-la-david-batsheva-be-reinstituted . Ask first about whether it's permissible to ride in a car, in traffic, anywhere in the world.

Comment: dont see the connection. it seems to me israelis are in far greater danger according to the natural way then someone riding a car. they need nothing less than a miracle to be saved from the tens of thousands of missiles pointed at them besides iran which is pursuing nukes and swore to wipe israel off the map and the chemical weapons soon to be in the hands of terrorists

Comment: This question would be much stronger if you could cite a source indicating that this is, in fact, the case. Not only that missiles exist and in the wrong hands, but that they constitute a newly grave danger for the average resident of Israel. Your intuition is so, but my intuition is that Israelis were in much greater danger in the 1940s, 50s, and 60s, not to mention practically any time between the times of Yehoshua' and those of the Second Temple.

Comment: Re "it seems to me israelis are in far greater danger according to the natural way then someone riding a car", see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11463.

Comment: it is well known that syria has hundreds of tons of chemical weapons and iran is pursuing nukes which it swore to use. egypt is ruled by hamas like terrorist, turkey is headed that way. obviously things are headed for major war and the israeli army has no defense for missile onslaughts as we saw in the lebanon war

Comment: @IsaacMoses i agree that in the 40s-60s etc, but i would ask the same question then too. just because they made it through then doesnt mean they will continue to do so. the fact is israel is headed for a dangerous war

Comment: Have you seen anyone in any position of secular knowledge and authority advocating that people leave Israel for safety reasons?

Comment: i have spoken to a reliable source who told me that the israeli army has no solution for the current missile threat from lebanon, syria, iran, gaza.

Comment: Here's what the US State Department had to say as of [six months ago](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/tw/tw_5841.html): "Personal safety conditions in major metropolitan areas, including Tel Aviv and Haifa and their surrounding regions, are comparable to or better than those in other major global cities. Tourists, students, and businesspeople from around the world are welcome."

Comment: yes, that's only during nonwartime.

Comment: what solution do you see for the tens or hundreds of thousands of missiles which sooner or later will be raining down on israeli cities (according to the normal order) some conventional some not. plus the enemies within, millions of arabs with death in their eyes.

Comment: "sooner or later will" - [citation needed]. I will not engage with your speculation. This stuff is important enough that if it's true, there's an authoritative, impeachable, source you can cite.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9215/discussion-between-isaac-moses-and-good-ole-ray)

Comment: In addition to @IsaacMoses's suggestion that you cite a source that that is the case, I'd advocate that you cite a source that leaving Israel is safer.

Comment: i think this aswers both: "Israel’s Prime Minister, Benjamin Netanyahu, recently said that Israel is “the most threatened nation on the planet.” He was referring to the threatening ring of missiles aimed at the Jewish state from regimes such as Hamas, Hezbollah, Syria, and Iran http://canadafreepress.com/index.php/article/55711

Comment: Why ask from veneshmartem meod? Wouldn't it be a stronger proof from vechai bahem?

Answer (score 6):

This question is based entirely on an assumption that "anyone living in Israel is in grave danger," but it cites no source to back this statement of fact up.

On the contrary, here is a source that indicates that people living in Israel, in general, are *not* in grave danger. The US State Department issues [Travel Warnings](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/tw/tw_1764.html) "when long-term, protracted conditions that make a country dangerous or unstable lead the State Department to recommend that Americans avoid or consider the risk of travel to that country." Grave danger to anyone living in a particular country would seem to rise to this level. However, the currently-effective Travel Warning for ["Israel, the West Bank and Gaza"](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/tw/tw_5841.html), dated December 20, 2012, includes the blanket statement:

> Personal safety conditions in major metropolitan areas, including Tel Aviv and Haifa and their surrounding regions, are comparable to or better than those in other major global cities. Tourists, students, and businesspeople from around the world are welcome.

The State Department notes specific hazards to be aware of and avoid in specific locations, but it contains no recommendation to leave Israel. Given that this institution, which has access to more information about the security situation than the average person, sees no general "grave danger" and sees no need to call for evacuation, it seems difficult to make a Halachic decision that presupposes the existence of such a danger or necessity of evacuation for the purpose of sustaining one's life.

---

Similarly, the Israel Ministry of Tourism [says](http://www.goisrael.com/Tourism_Eng/Tourist%20Information/Planning%20your%20trip/Pages/Israel%20Frequently%20Asked%20Questions.aspx):

> **Is it safe to travel to Israel?**
>
> Israel is an extremely safe country to visit and to tour. In 2008, three million tourists came to Israel, an all-time record, and all three million went  back home safe and sound. We would not encourage tourists to come if we felt they would be in the slightest danger.

Comment: the source is: "due to the recent advances in missile technology and WMP by Arab enemies who are hell-bent on destroying Israel". i thought it was well known that iran, hezbolla, gaza are all fielding hundreds of thousands of missiles (and iran's developing nukes) in preparation for a war with israel. not to mention the islamization of egypt by the MBrotherhood and the islamization of turkey

Comment: the travel warning to israel here http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/tw/tw_5841.html says: "The security environment remains complex in Israel and the West Bank, and U.S. citizens need to be aware of the continuing risks of travel to these areas". in my opinion the only reason the americans are not sounding red lights is because the situation is currently calm but everyone living in israel knwos this is jsut the calm b4 the storm

Comment: Sounds like [Bamidbar 13:33](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.13.33?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all).

Comment: there's a big difference between tourist travel and living there. a tourist stays short term and can assess the situation before going.

Answer (score 3):

Even if, in theory, you're right that one should leave Israel if it is more dangerous than, say, the United States — and I don't know whether you are — it isn't. The life expectancy in Israel is 80.69 years; in the United States, 77.97. That is, despite the missiles and bombs, one can expect to live longer in Israel than in the United States: it is, overall, less dangerous. In fact, the only countries with a life expectancy greater than Israel's are (least to most) Sweden, France, Iceland, Italy, Australia, Hong Kong, Switzerland, and, at 82.73 years, Japan.

Source: World Health Organization, 2012, as tabulated by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy&oldid=559904560#List_from_the_WHO_.22GDB_2010.22_study).

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11463/2

Comment: maybe, but as i pointed out in the question, new technologies have changed the situation. israel'sedge used to be aerial supremacy. missiles have changed that.

Comment: @good_ole_ray, I guess we can wait and see what the life expectancy is in Israel in a few years. I doubt it will change much, and I pray that it won't go down.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53480

Comment: @ray and msh210, here's an update from 9 years thence: per the latest update to [that WP entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy), based on World Bank 2020 data, the gap in life expectancy between Israel and the US has widened, to 82.7/77.3.